# Drawing Bounding box for an object in an image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an image, in which I have detected an object using Connected Components Labeling using the Aforge library in C#. Now the object detected can be of any shape. I want to find the 4 sided smallest bounding box which overlaps the complete object. I see some methods which find the bounding box which are rectangle such that the 4 sides are parallel to the sides of the image. The image below shows and obj which is bounded by two quadrilaterals shown in red and green. The red one is the one that I don't want. The green one, I want to know how to get.
Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 5):

I doubt you will find a simple ready-made solution in the common libraries.

If you are ready to spend some effort, a good approach is with "rotating calipers".

1) find the convex hull of the object; this is a convex polygon.

Then note that the tightest rectangular box (can be with minimum area or minimum perimeter, up to you) will have a side along an edge of the hull and the three other sides through a vertex of the hull.

2) consider every edge in turn (rotating) as a main side candidate and find the three other vertexes. You will convince yourself that by moving from edge to edge along the hull, you can update these three vertexes very simply, so that the total number of operations remains O(N).

For every fit of the rectangle, you will compute your compactness criterion, and keep the one that achieves the lowest score.

http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/rotcal.html

[image]